# pushing a new card object to the nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this structure in my `Accounts` Model:

```
{
  cards: {
    starter: [],
    intermediate: [],
    advanced: [ {Object}, {Object}, {Object} ]
  },
  firstName: 'Sepideh',
  email: 'sepideh@example.com',
}
```

The `Objects` inside `cards.advanced` array above are like:

```
{
  cards: [
    { // this is a single card object 
      cardTitle: 'this card is for you',
      performance: [],
      cardID: 32,
    }
  ],
  unit: 3 // this is the unit we want to push our new card object into
}
```

Assuming I can access the document above (or account in other words) with the given email:

```
const account = await db.Account.findOne({ email: 'sepideh@example.com' });
```

How can we push a new card object into the nested cards array with `unit: 3` (yes so far this is the only unit) property and save Sepideh account like this:

```
{
    cards: {
        starter: [],
        intermediate: [],
        advanced: [
            {
                cards: [
                    { // this is a single card object 
                        cardTitle: 'this card is for you',
                        performance: [],
                        cardID: 32,
                    }

                    { // this is new pushed card object 
                        cardTitle: 'this card is for me',
                        performance: [],
                        cardID: 33,
                    }
                ],
                unit: 3 // this is the unit we want to push our new card object into
            },
            {Object},
            {Object}
        ] // end of advanced array
    },
    firstName: 'Sepideh',
    email: 'sepideh@example.com',
}
```

I have tried to select the unit 3 of the document using these guys and none of them worked:

```
const userUnit = await account.findOne({'cards.advanced.unit': unit});

const userUnit = await account.findOne({'cards.advanced.unit': unit});

const userUnit = await account.find({}, {'cards.advanced.unit': {$elemMatch: {unit: unit}}}); 

const userUnit = await db.Account.findOne({ email: email, 'cards.advanced.unit': unit});
```

Then I would push my new card object to the `userUnit` and call `await account.save();`

The only thing which is working is pure JavaScript code like this to select:

```
const userUnit = account.cards.advanced.find(e => e.unit == unit);
```

This time I cannot save the changes to the database... (I don't know how to save it..)

How would you do this?

Comment: In your sample document, `advanced` is an array of arrays whereas your last code snippet queries `advanced` array based on `unit` directly. There is a difference between https://mongoplayground.net/p/mmNzS1hYhCm and https://mongoplayground.net/p/P27QGH9Eey9 which version is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the comment edited the question, actually cmd console shows objects like [Object] !!

Comment: @SaraRee, you can also use ```JSON.stringify(object)``` to get a JSON and format your JSON and output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator directly along with the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which allows you to specify which sub-element should be updated:

```
await db.Account.update({ email: "sepideh@example.com", "cards.advanced.unit": 3 },
        { $push: { "cards.advanced.$.cards": { cardTitle: 'this card is for me', performance: [], cardID: 33 } } })
```

If you want your path to be evaluated dynamically you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names):

```
let path = "advanced";
await db.Account.update(
    { email: "sepideh@example.com", ["cards." + path + ".unit"]: 3 },            
    { $push: { ["cards." + path + ".$.cards"]: { cardTitle: 'this card is for me', performance: [], cardID: 33 } } })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YqEh_j5cuLp)

Comment: What if I want to do levels dynamically can I use a variable holding those strings ?